# dashboard table component link to account record

Tags: dashboard

I have a dashboard report that list selected accounts.  How do I make each of those account records on the report/dashboard be an active link to that account record - detail page.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest thing to do is to edit the dashboard and then select the particular chart properties (wrench icon on the top right of the chart object) and on the component data tab set the drop down menu to "drill down to record detail page".